# ffmpeg: not found (Conda Env + Gunicorn + Nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, ffmpeg, gunicorn, anaconda3

I have installed `ffmpeg` and can run it from command line. I have anaconda installed and get different result for `which ffmpeg` command as follow:

- `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` (base env)
- `/root/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/ffmpeg` (myenv)

`python app.py` - The app uses Flask. I've tested it on localhost it is working as expected.

Ran it with `gunicorn` still working locally.

When I deploy it using **Nginx** it doesn't work. It can't find `ffmpeg`. I get the error `gunicorn[23436]: /bin/sh: 1: ffmpeg: not found`.

My usage inside python file is as follows:
`subprocess.call('/root/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/ffmpeg ...)` (I tried it with `ffmpeg`, full path and anaconda path - still to no success)

I doubt there is something about Nginx that I'm missing, does it need special configuration for executables. Server config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myapp/myapp.sock;
        client_max_body_size 30M;
    }
}
```

I had installed `ffmpeg` with `pip` but then I deleted it. It doesn't have anything to do with the error since I can run it locally without problems.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @arunna It has been I while, I think I resolved the issue by writing a service and providing environment directory `Environment="PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin"` followed by `ExecStart=/root/anaconda3/envs/<app-name>/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:<app-name>.sock -m 007 wsgi:app`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by writing a service and providing environment directory

```
Environment="PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

followed by

```
ExecStart=/root/anaconda3/envs/<app-name>/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:<app-name>.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```